# Не работает скрипт с включенным кэшированием браузера

Tags: html, jquery

Есть одна из моих [первых работ](https://velikhanov.github.io/myworks/NurayHouse/index.html). Решил посмотреть как она работает, чтобы в будущем загрузить в свое портфолио. Сайт изначально был на php и реализована была там многоязычность на нем, но github pages с php не дружит, пришлось делать на jQuery. Вроде все нормально, но т.к. у меня в хроме отключено кэширование я не заметил баг. Если оно будет включено, то один из скриптов не подгружается. А именно тот, который отвечает за раскрытие бургер меню. Пытался ставить для того скрипта async, работает но через раз. В чем может быть проблема?

Напишите если какие то скрипты надо приложить.

А вот сам скрипт, который не хочет грузиться:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//active
var path = window.location.href;
$('.nav__link, .nav__link_child').each(function() {
if (this.href === path) {
 $(this).addClass('active');
}
});
$('.nav__link_child').each(function() {
if (this.href === path) {
 $('.nav__link.arr.d').addClass('active');
}
});
$('.nav__link_footer').each(function() {
if (this.href === path) {
 $(this).addClass('_active');
 $(this).parent().addClass('activelist');
 }
});
/*Dropdown menu toggle*/
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $(".child").slideToggle(500);
  });
/*Menu icon toggle*/
  $(".triggericon").click(function() {
    $(".parent").slideToggle(500);
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() > 870 ){
        $('.parent').removeAttr('style');
      }
  });
/*hamburger menu icon*/
  $('.triggericon').click(function () {

   $('.triggericon').toggleClass('open');
 });
/*Arrow animation*/
    $(".nav__link.arr").click(function(){
        $(".arrow").toggleClass("arrow-active");
    });
});
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Как вы определяете, что скрипт не загружается? Он ведь в кеше уже второй раз и уже является загруженным.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev, точно! Но он не работает почему то.

Comment: У вас вверху страницы скрипт добавляет элементы на страницу, но позже, когда ответ от сервера придёт. А пока ответа нет, внизу страницы скрипт пытается что-то делать с элементами, которых ещё нет.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev, значит по идее надо как то заставить скрипт работать после полной загрузки шапки и футера. Есть мысли как это сделать?

Comment: Ну просто сделайте внутри функций загруженности шапки и футера вызов одной функции, которая посчитает сколько блоков загружено (0..2), и если все (2), то вызовет функцию, которая у вас сейчас внизу в документ-реди.

Comment: Или можно ещё проще - постоянно вызывать ту функцию что внизу в документ-реди, но в ней в начале делать "если не найдены сейчас нужные блоки, то ретурн"